# How to add transition to this javascript function

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, transition

I am not able to add A transition to this Javascript function.

```
function togglediv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: As you used the `css-transitions` tag, did you try to Google "css transition via javascript"?

Comment: Can you post your html too? How are you call your `togglediv` function.

Comment: [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o9n0eL2n/)

Answer (score 1):

The `display` property cannot be animated.

What you could do is fade in/out by animate `opacity`. Add a css class 'out' which is defined like

```
.out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/s42stnyw/2/